# Dynamic Linq Library can't handling one on many relationship in select clause

Tags: asp.net, linq, dynamic-linq, linq-expressions, predicatebuilder

I would like to get records from the database using Dynamic Linq Library [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/). How can I write query for select parent records along with list of child records. For example there is One-on-Many relationship between Question and Answers table. QuestionID is a Foreign Key column in Answers table.

It is very simple if i give column name in where clause when i am not going to use Dynamic Linq Library [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/).

```
var LinQResult=db.Questions
            .Include(f=>f.Answers).Where(f=>f.Email=="someEmail").ToList();
```

I have no question on above query and i can simply render the content on razor views or any web forms.

If i am going to use Dynamic Linq Library [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/), I have a search criteria in string format like below,

```
string SearchCreteria = "Email=\"SomeValue\"";
```

Passing the above dynamic search criteria in where clause below,

```
var QueryBuilder = (from q in db.Questions
                    join a in db.Answers on q.QuestionID equals a.QuestionID into answer
                    from a in answer.DefaultIfEmpty()                                
                    select new { q,a}).Distinct().AsQueryable();

var Result = QueryBuilder.Where(SearchCreteria);
```

How can I convert/add above Result into a strongly typed list below

```
List<QuestionVM> questionVM=new List<QuestionVM> ();
public class QuestionVM
        {
            public Question Question { get; set; }
            public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it I think.

```
var queryBuilder = (from q in db.Questions.Include(itm  => itm.Answers)
join a in db.Answers on q.QuestionID equals a.QuestionID
where a.Email.equals(SearchCriteria)
select q).Distinct().ToList();

var questionVM = new List<QuestionVM>();
foreach(var q in queryBuilder)
{
   questionVM.add(new QuestionVM
   {
      Question = q,
      Answers = q.Answers.Where(itm => itm != null).Select(itm => itm.QuestionID == q.ID)
   });
}
```

Comment: I am getting `q.Answers` as null even i have data at line `Answers=q.Answers.Where(q.Answer!=null).`

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at after the queryBuilder statement, does it have any Answers?